# Merge direct HTML siblings into one in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I need to merge direct html siblings into just one in page code including text nodes.

```
<div>some text 
<b>some text</b> som
e text <b>text</b><b> more text</b> some te
xt</div>
```

This is actualy output after editing the code using rangy and jQuery and i need to clear it after the editing so it will look like this:

```
<div>some text <b>some text</b> some text <b>text more text</b> some text</div>
```

I would like to use jQuery to do this. I am aware of functions unwrap() and wrapAll() but i cant combine them effectively.
Thanks for any clue or help!

Comment: So, essentially, all you want to do is get rid of the linebreaks?

Comment: I think what he wants is to turn this `<b>text</b><b> more text</b>` into this `<b>text more text</b>`. Actually that's a really good question.

Comment: @PatrickEvans no there not `<b>text more text</b>` has been combined from `<b>text</b><b> more text</b>`.

Comment: Why u cann't use replace function!!

Comment: I think he wants to combine elements only if they are the same.  Though, I don't know why you would bother

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to iterate over child nodes one by one; comparing nodes with previous one and combine if necessary. It can be as complicated as you want; but here is a start:

```
$("div").each(function (i) {
    $(this).find("*").each(function () {
        var that = this.previousSibling;
        if (that && that.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE && that.tagName === this.tagName) {
            var node = document.createElement(this.tagName);
            while (that.firstChild) {
                node.appendChild(that.firstChild);
            }
            while (this.firstChild) {
                node.appendChild(this.firstChild);
            }
            this.parentNode.insertBefore(node, this.nextSibling);
            that.parentNode.removeChild(that);
            this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
        }
    });
});
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/FTTLC/7/)

Comment: Great! Many thanks! I added this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(/\r?\n/g, ""); at the end so also new line breaks dissapeared. My hero! ;)

Answer (score 2):

If i understood your question correctly, you wanted to combine elements that are next to each other of the same type.

```
var $div = $("#mydiv");
console.log($div.html());

$div.contents().each(function(){
    if (this.nodeType != 1) return;
    while (this.nextSibling && this.nextSibling.tagName == this.tagName) {
        this.innerHTML = (this.innerHTML + this.nextSibling.innerHTML);
        this.parentNode.removeChild(this.nextSibling);
    }
});

console.log($div.html());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/X8LYu/2/

If you also wanted to remove the new-line characters, it would change to this:

```
var $div = $("div");
console.log($div.html());

$div.contents().each(function(){
    if (this.nodeType == 3) {
        this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace(/\n/g,"");
        return;
    }
    if (this.nodeType != 1) return;
    while (this.nextSibling && this.nextSibling.tagName == this.tagName) {
        this.innerHTML = (this.innerHTML + this.nextSibling.innerHTML).replace(/\n/g,"");
        this.parentNode.removeChild(this.nextSibling);
    }
});

console.log($div.html());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/X8LYu/3/

I don't write code in this way very often, so there might be better ways of handling this.

Comment: This will of course destroy any attributes on elements that come after the first element in a set.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div').html(function(_, oldHTML) {
   return oldHTML.replace(/\n/g, '');
}).children().filter(function () {
    return this.nextSibling 
           && this.nextSibling.nodeName === this.nodeName;
}).text(function (_, oldText) {
    return oldText + this.parentNode.removeChild(this.nextSibling).textContent;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tVZJV/